# Finding shortest path

Tags: shortest-path

I have a set of points in a graph. I want to find the shortest path connecting a subset of this graph using lines which are either horizontal, vertical or at 45 degree left or right. Can anybody suggest an algorithm to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to modify the solution for [Rectilinear minimum steniar tree problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_Steiner_tree).